# I have a working laravel select query. how do i add filters?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, geolocation, xampp

hey guys hows it going? thanks in advance.
I have written a working function in a laravel model which does a geosearch and returns the order in search by distance. It works beautifully.

```
 public static function searchByDistance($distance, $unit)
{
    //spatial queries
   // $circle_radius = 6371; 
    $circle_radius = 3959; 
    $max_distance = $distance;
    $lat = Auth::user()->getLoc()->latitude;
    $lng = Auth::user()->getLoc()->longitude;
    //get all nearby places
     $nearbyusers = DB::select(
           'SELECT * FROM
                (SELECT users.id, users.country, places.name, places.state_code, places.latitude, places.longitude, (' . $circle_radius . ' * acos(cos(radians(' . $lat . ')) * cos(radians(latitude)) *
                cos(radians(longitude) - radians(' . $lng . ')) +
                sin(radians(' . $lat . ')) * sin(radians(latitude))))
                AS distance
                FROM users
                LEFT JOIN places ON users.suburb=places.name) AS distances
            WHERE distance < ' . $max_distance . '
            ORDER BY distance;
     ');        
   $nearbyusers = (object)$nearbyusers;
    return $nearbyusers;
}
```

however i have one issue. I want to call the function, return a query and keep being able to `add ->where()` operations to it until im ready to use `get()` and return the results.

I cant use `where() or get()` and i know why. its not in the right format.
is there a way someone could help me modify/alter the function so that i could add more filters once i return the `$nearbyusers` value?

cheers

Comment: Which ORM / query builder are you using, if any ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet Looks like eloquent.

Comment: Do you want to add `where() or get()` on the above query or any other query ?

Comment: im using eloquent. i want to add where()s and at the end a get()
reason being is i can get a search by distance in order of distance by the above query and im excited i cracked it!

however i want to be able to add more filters outside that, such as between what ages, etc etc

Comment: is there a way you could help me please convert this raw query to ORM eloquent? i have been trying unsuccessfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to look at the underlying Fluent query builder system. As it stands, your query is standalone. It's also possible that this particular one may need to stay standalone.

In order to hook in to Fluent in the way you want, you'll need to pass in the query (this should get auto-resolved), add to it, then return the query. In relation to your current function, that will likely require a fairly different approach than what you have (though what you have is a good model for the query that you want to end up with).

Have a look at [the docs about query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#query-scopes), which may be addressing how you're trying to integrate it. Also, have a look at the code itself, [such as this one for the JoinClause function](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.php), to get an idea of how to structure your code.

The base elements are that you need to take and return the query object. This means that it can't be a static method (it needs the object instance), and depending on the approach you take, you'll either be returning the passed-in `$query` object (scopes) or `$this` (the instance of them model object, itself).

You'll need to figure out a way to encapsulate the query you have into just the segment you need. It may be something like:

```
public function byDistance($distance, $unit) {
    $lat = Auth::user()->getLoc()->latitude;
    $lng = Auth::user()->getLoc()->longitude;

    return $this->join(DB::select('SELECT users.id, users.country, places.name, places.state_code, places.latitude, places.longitude, (' . $circle_radius . ' * acos(cos(radians(' . $lat . ')) * cos(radians(latitude)) *
            cos(radians(longitude) - radians(' . $lng . ')) +
            sin(radians(' . $lat . ')) * sin(radians(latitude)))
            AS distance'), 
         'users.id', 'distance.user_id = users.id')
    ->leftJoin('places', 'users.suburb = places.name')
    ->where('distance', '<', $distance)
    ->orderBy('distance');
}
```

Notice the lack of an actual `select` within the query building part (the nested select notwithstanding), and the lack of any type of actual fetching. What this does is add to the current query, which will then be built when `get` or other fetch function is finally called. This gives you a discrete segment of a larger query that you can then add to when calling it.

Comment: thank you that looks very helpful. however i tried it out and it doesnt work. I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')'

and i cant figure out where the error is. there shouldnt be a syntax error?
also its querying two tables. if that matters. one is users one is places but i want to return the users from those places in order of distance

Comment: shauna. your function has syntax errors. can i actually please have a direct solution? all i want is something that works. i can read books later. PLEASE.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to have work done for you, largely because we don't have the insight into your project that you do. You're going to have to figure out the exact details for your particular case, answers here will only guide you in the right direction.

Comment: well there are syntax errors in your sql. so that is currently taking me in a bad direction.


SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS distance' at line 4 (SQL: SELECT users.id, users.country, places.name, places.state_code, places.latitude, places.longitude, (6371 * acos(cos(radians(-34.42588)) * cos(radians(latitude)) *
cos(radians(longitude) - radians(150.89982)) +
sin(radians(-34.42588)) * sin(radians(latitude)))
AS distance)

Comment: All I did was a quick convert from your query into the Fluent syntax. I prefaced it with "*something like*", because it was merely an example for what you would end up with when you converted it properly.

Comment: Hey @happinin, you're being really rude to someone who tried pretty hard to help you.

Comment: (Above comment refers to some now-deleted comments.)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [official documentation for raw expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions) I think it's what you're looking for. Anyway you have to change your raw query to a "builded" query like so:

```
$nearbyusersquery = DB::table('users')
    ->select(DB::RAW('SELECT users.id, users.country, places.name, places.state_code, places.latitude, places.longitude, (' . $circle_radius . ' * acos(cos(radians(' . $lat . ')) * cos(radians(latitude)) *
            cos(radians(longitude) - radians(' . $lng . ')) +
            sin(radians(' . $lat . ')) * sin(radians(latitude))))
            AS distance'))
    ->leftJoin('places', 'users.suburb', '=', 'places.name')
    ->where('distance', '<', $max_distance)
    ->orderBy('distance');      

return $nearbyusersquery
```

In this way your method will return a `Builder` object that can be chained with other statements.

Comment: tried that for some reason says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: My fault I've writtten `select(DB:raw('...')` instead of `select(DB:raw('...'))`

Comment: @happinin I highly recommend reviewing the Community FAQ and help center (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) for guidelines on what's expected here.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with sql. For example:

```
   $filtr = "";
$filtr2 = "";

If (something)
 $filtr =" and field = var";

If (somethingelse)
   $filtr2 = " and field2 = other_var";

// this can be in the elloquent query
$query = "select .... 
from .... 
Where 1=1 
     $filtr
     $filtr2
";
```

EDIT

```
//assuming the country Id is passed to your controller
// first initialize the filter as empty string
$countryFilter = "";

// if the country is not null or empty replace the filter
if ($country != null && $country != "")  
    $countryFilter = "and country = $countryFilter";

$nearbyusers = DB::select(
           'SELECT * FROM
                (SELECT users.id, users.country, places.name, places.state_code, places.latitude, places.longitude, (' . $circle_radius . ' * acos(cos(radians(' . $lat . ')) * cos(radians(latitude)) *
                cos(radians(longitude) - radians(' . $lng . ')) +
                sin(radians(' . $lat . ')) * sin(radians(latitude))))
                AS distance
                FROM users
                LEFT JOIN places ON users.suburb=places.name) AS distances
            WHERE distance < ' . $max_distance . '
            -- if no country was selected then it will just be an empty line
            $countryFilter
            ORDER BY distance;
     ');
```

Comment: can you please be more thorough. i get treated like a newbie programmer on here enough as is, and i cant seem to get a straight answer off anybody. can anyone actually provide a working solution without syntax errors or..... what

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry I don't know what filters you want to apply that's why I gave you a basic filter and you can modify it as you need

Comment: if you want to add filters AFTER the query has been executed then you probably will need a new function, if not you could add the filter to the query you already have.

Comment: not sure if is what you want but I edited the answer, take a look.

Comment: oh man
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '$countryFilter
ORDER BY distance' at line 10

Comment: I get this error everytime i attempt to try this style. cant figure out why, mine works good but when i try everything you guys link me, it crashes. could you please give me something that works and show me how to call it? im hitting a wall no matter what i try

Comment: Try to remove the dots infront and back of $max_distance, also what value does it have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149155/discussion-between-disturb-and-happinin).

Comment: cant tell. because of syntax errors. and also removing the dots in front of max_distance gives more syntax errors. because the dots should be there!

Answer (score 0):

well again as usual, solved it myself. the issue was so simple. all you had to do look up user objects which matched with the results and push them into an array. then return that array and you can use the functions! So if you ever want to get passable objects from raw queries, this is what you do. Thank you again for your helpful answers guys. The question really was so simple. In the end i fiddled with it to work instead of getting any answers off the internet.

```
//spatial queries        

                    $circle_radius = 6371;       

                   // $circle_radius = 3959; 


                $max_distance = request('distance');
                $lat = Auth::user()->getLoc()->latitude;
                $lng = Auth::user()->getLoc()->longitude;

                //get all nearby places
                 $nearbyusers = DB::select(
                       'SELECT * FROM
                            (SELECT users.id, users.country, places.name, places.state_code, places.latitude, places.longitude, (' . $circle_radius . ' * acos(cos(radians(' . $lat . ')) * cos(radians(latitude)) *
                            cos(radians(longitude) - radians(' . $lng . ')) +
                            sin(radians(' . $lat . ')) * sin(radians(latitude))))
                            AS distance
                            FROM users
                            LEFT JOIN places ON users.suburb=places.name) AS distances
                        WHERE distance < ' . $max_distance . '
                        ORDER BY distance;
                 ');      

                 $users = [];

                 foreach($nearbyusers as $user)
                 {
                    array_push($users, User::where('id', $user->id)->first());
                 }



               //$nearbyusers = (object)$nearbyusers;


                return Response::json( array( 
                'searchsuccess' => (String) view('members.yessearch', compact('users')) 
                ) );
```